# Construction of an algebra with prescribed representation of the automorphism group.

Tags: lie-groups, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, gr.group-theory

For this discussion, $G$ is a compact semisimple Lie Group.

For many of the common representations of compact groups, there is a realization of the representation as the automorphisms of some algebraic structure. For example, the adjoint representation of any group $G$ is realized as the automorphisms of $LG$, the standard representation of $SO(n)$ is as the stabilizer of the volume form on $\mathbb{R}^n$, the 7-dimensional representation of $G_2$ is realized as the automorphisms of the imaginary octonions or as the stabilizer of a certain 3-form on $\mathbb{R}^7$, and so forth.

My particular interest for this question is in the automorphisms of algebras over $\mathbb{R}$ (although for Question 1, I don't care about the ground field).

> **Question 1:** Given a representation of $G$ (not necessarily irreducible) is there a general method of constructing an algebra (over the appropriate ground field) such that $G$ is the group of automorphisms of this algebra acting by the prescribed representation?

My gut feeling is that a solution to this question in general would be related to the construction of Cartan Products, but even given the irreducible summands of the representation I don't see how to make an algebra which is not a direct sum of algebras (the problem with a direct sum of algebras is that it can have larger automorphism group than $G$).

Since this is such a general question, I understand it may have no easy answer. However, I do have a specific example in mind; some of my recent experimentation has suggested that if a representation has certain properties, any algebra on which this representation acts as the full set of automorphisms should also have certain nice properties. One specific case I would like to know about is a 16-dimensional representation of $G_2$ which contains two trivial summands and one copy of the 14-dimensional adjoint representation.

> **Question 2:** Does anyone have an example of a 16-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-algebra whose automorphism group is $G_2$ with the decomposition of the automorphic action given by $1\oplus1\oplus 14$. For this it would be enough to describe the bilinear multiplication.

Note that I do not care if the algebra is a unital ring, is commutative, associative, or any other particular property; any 16-dimensional algebra structure whose automorphism group is provably $G_2$ with the given representation will suffice for me to test my ideas.

Comment: Also, as this is my first time using the gray boxes to highlight my questions, if anyone can tell me how to correct all the math formatting in them that would be much appreciated so I know how to do it in the future.

Comment: I fixed the grey boxes. To make them (and the math formatting) display properly, begin each paragraph with the > character.

Comment: For question 2, you need to pick the 14-dimensional $G_2$-module, add two trivial ones, call it $V$, and see if there is a trivial summand in $\hom(V\otimes V,V)$. That gives you all possibly non-associative, possibly non-unitary multiplications which are $G_2$-equivariant; this computation you can do with LiE, for example. I wonder if there are *any* such maps...

Comment: «you need to» should really be «a good start would be to»...

Comment: @Mariano: If $V$ is the 16-dimensional representation in question then I calculate that $hom(V\otimes V,V)$ is 15 dimensional, so it seems like there should actually be lots of such algebraic structures. In light of this, what exactly do you mean by "see if there is a trivial summand in $hom(V\otimes V,V)$"?

If this method works, it suggests a similar method for answering Question 1 as well.

Comment: @ARupinski: A linear map $V\otimes V \to V$ is $G_2$-equivariant if and only if it is a fixed point for the linear action of $G_2$ on $\mathrm{hom}(V\otimes V,V)$ given be $(g⋅f)(x)=gf(g^{−1}x)$. I presume that's why Mariano suggests you should "see if there is a trivial summand in $\mathrm{hom}(V\otimes V,V)$." But since LiE tells me that this trivial summand has dimension $15$ for the $V$ you're considering, that's the space you must have computed. Out of curiosity, may I ask how you computed the dimension? 

Comment: @Bart: Thanks for clarifying the trivial summand comment. When decomposed into irreducibles, $V\otimes V$ contains 5 copies of the 14 dimensional representation and 5 copies of the trivial representation. Since V contains 1 copy of the 14 dimensional representation and 2 copies of the trivial representation, the dimension of intertwiners is 5x1 for the 14-dimensional piece and 5x2 for the trivial piece, leading to my count of 15 dimensions.

Comment: @ARupinski: Thanks for the reply. And how did you decompose $V\otimes V$ into irreducibles? Is there an easy rule for $\mathsf{G}_2$?

Comment: @Bart: I just ran the decomposition of $14\otimes 14$ through LiE; this is the only non-obvious part of V⊗V (the other parts being obvious by distributivity of the tensor product). Since the dimension is so small, one could have also computed the decomposition of $14\otimes 14$ by hand using Klimyk's formula.

Comment: @ARupinski: Can I email you?

Comment: @Nick: Sure, I just sent you an email from my address

Comment: Something seemingly close to the spirit of your computations, but with prescribed Lie algebras as derivations instead of automorphism groups, is going in: S. Okubo, Construction of non-associative algebras from representation modules of simple Lie algebras, Algebras, Groups and Geom. 3 (1986), 60-127, http://www-lib.kek.jp/cgi-bin/img_index?200035587 .
